# How to rejoin `ReadHalf` and `WriteHalf` into a `TcpStream`

Tags: tcp, rust, stream, rust-tokio

Is there a way to rejoin a Tokio `ReadHalf` and `WriteHalf` into a `TcpStream` after a [split](https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio/doc/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html?search=#method.split)?

```
let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080").await?;
let (reader, writer) = stream.split();

// re-join pseudo-code
let stream: TcpStream = (reader, writer).join();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cargo doc](https://docs.rs/tokio-io/0.2.0-alpha.6/tokio_io/split/index.html)

```
To restore this read/write object from its split::ReadHalf and split::WriteHalf use unsplit.
```

Comment: At least in current versions, [`tokio::net::tcp::ReadHalf`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.24.1/tokio/net/tcp/struct.ReadHalf.html) does not have an `unsplit` method.